# how to write variables to an empty file and import this file in python

Tags: python, import, overwrite

Here is the structure of all the files:

1. Project

   - setup

     - default.py
     - config.py
     - _ init_.py
     - test.py
   - setting.py

I want to import all variables from setup.default.py and setting.py to setup._ init _.py. Then if variable in setting.py has the same name as variable in default.py, overwrite to the value in setting.py (i.e those addin variables). Not sure if setattr() may work, but I think I need to convert to object first. Is it available to write a loop for overwriting if I have many variables need to overwrite?

In the test.py file, only refer to variable using config.names. The config.py is an empty file. My idea is after initialization, all variables in default.py and setting.py will write to config.py, so that the test.py can import config.py, but I am not sure how to implement this in the init.py. Additionally, my python version is 3.6, some module is not available in this version.

```py
# default.py
# Here are all defaults variables and associated values

local_root = r'c:\temp\project\cache'
local_input = local_root + r'inputs'
local_output = local_root + r'outputs'
addin_location = r'c:\user\...
addin_name = r'project_addin'
addin_version = r'1.1'
```

```py
# setting.py

addin_location = r'D:\addin\...
addin_name = r'test_addin'
addin_version = r'1.2'

env_prefix = 'ccp'
env_location ='cme'
env_suffix = ''
```

```py
# config.py
#This is an empty file
```

```py
# _init_.py
from setup import default
import setting

setattr(default, default.addin_location, setting.addin_location)
some functions/methods to write variables to config.py and overwrite the same variable names?

_initialized = False

if not _initialized:

    functions/methods?

    _initialized = True
```

```py
# test.py
# Only use config.names in this file

from setup import config
import os

prefix = '_'.join([config.env_prefix, config.env_location])
env_type = env_suffix
root = config.local_input

def get_env_path(root, prefix, env_type):
    return os.path.join(root, get_name(prefix, env_type)
...
...
...
```

Comment: Yes, loops are available in Python. You can do everything in loops that you can do outside of loops. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The key part is not the loop, I want to know how to import config.py and use the config.names because it is an empty file at the beginning.

Comment: If you just want to store some default values like env variables, you can use this 3rd party lib, decouple: https://pypi.org/project/python-decouple/

Comment: @MenglongLi Thanks for your advice. Is there any non 3rd party lib approach to work this out?